# Show Shapes Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

Show Shapes Based on Cell Value

I want to show and hide shapes on a sheet based on the cell value >1. If cell A1 = 1 the shape should be visible and for value is 0, the shape should be hidden. i need the code for compelete my job,

Comment: You can use either the Worksheet_change or _Calculate events, depending on whether the cell has a formula or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: We're glad that *you* need the code, but we *don't* need one. So, show us your efforts. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are the only two possible values 0 or 1?  @kevin999's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following Private Sub should work whether the cell value changes manually or as a result of a formula.  It assumes cell A1 contains the test value, and simply add the name of your shape to make it work:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = 1 Then
            Me.Shapes("Shape Name").Visible = True
            Else
                If ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = 0 Then
                Me.Shapes("Shape Name").Visible = False
                End If
        End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: The Change event is not triggered when a cell value changes as a result of a formula

Comment: Hi Tim Williams - I tested the code before posting & it did work when a simple formula was entered into A1: "=A2/2".  When a 2 or a 0 was input into A2, the shape appeared or disappeared accordingly.

Comment: That's because it detected the change in A2.  If an input from another sheet in involved then it would not fire.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I'll remember that in future.